# Is there a way to use or operator || on char in java?

Tags: java

Im new in programming, so this is kind of basic but I cant find an answer here on why is this keep happenning. "The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) char, char",can someone please help, its for our task. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice = (scan.next().charAt(0));
        switch (choice) {
        case ('A'||'a'):
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
            break;
        
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Java does not allow usage of logical operators inside the case statement. The bets way is to chain the case statement where the execution statement is similar. `case 1: case 2: //block to execute; break;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't logically OR together characters in Java.  The closest thing to what you want to do in Java might be:

```
switch (choice) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
    break;
}
```

Here we are letting both cases of `A` to flow to the same case.  Another option:

```
switch (Character.toUpperCase(choice)) {
    case 'A':
        System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
    break;
}
```

This approach first uppercases the input character, and then we only need to check uppercase letters in the `switch` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in some non-English locales, as explained in my answer.

Comment: There are locale considerations in many other areas of core Java.  We typically answer assuming an English locale.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace `switch` with regular `if` statement and use `||` operator:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice = scan.next().charAt(0);

        if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a') {
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
        }
    }
}
```

However, much better will be operating with `String` class. And `next()` from Scanner returns exactly String instance. With small modification it could be like:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String firstLetter = scan.next().substring(0, 1);

        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(firstLetter, "A")) {
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, used [equalsIgnoreCase()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) from `StringUtils` class.   You have to add this dependency to the project with your build manager.

Comment: Why use StringUtils class when String has an equalsIgnoreCase?

Comment: @k314159 `StringUtils#equalsIgnoreCase()` is null safe, whereas null must be considered with the base string methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert character to the lower or upper case:

```java
switch (Character.toLowerCase(choice)) {
    case 'a':    System.out.println("Wrong Answer");    break;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in some non-English locales, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have said, you can have only one value in each case statement. Other answers have suggested using two case statements. However, recent versions of Java (since version 13) have an enhanced `switch` statement which makes it much neater:

```
switch (choice) {
    case 'A', 'a' -> System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
}
```

See how much neater it is? Not only do you not need two case statements, but you don't need a `break` statement either.

Other answers have suggested using `Character.toLowerCase`, but there are problems with that. Consider this:

```
switch (Character.toLowerCase(choice)) {
    case 'i':
        System.out.println("Correct answer");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Wrong answer");
        break;
}
```

The problem is `Character.toLowerCase` is sensitive to the current locale. If a user in Turkey runs the above, and types `I`, they'll get "Wrong answer" instead of correct answer. This is because in Turkish, the lowercase equivalent of the letter I is not i, but ı (an i without a dot). Similar problems occur with `toUpperCase` and in some other languages. I wouldn't recommend using toLowerCase/toUpperCase for this reason.